# delete parameters in URL

Tags: zend-framework2

I have kind of a basic understanding problem.

If I start my application:
http://localhost/cheyenne/public/
I have of course no post parameters in my start url
If I take a link with post parameters like edit for example, I get this URL
http://localhost/cheyenne/public/arbeitskalender/edit/nr/2
still everything is fine
If I take another link of my navigation, different part of my application, the former parameters follow
http://localhost/cheyenne/public/bibliothek/edit/nr/2/buchnr/2

In some way I have to delete the post parameters, how can I do that? Is there a possibility, every time I take my navigation menue?

I think it doesn´t matter, but here the navigation part out of my layout.phtml:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'arbeitskalender', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Arbeitskalender</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'bibliothek', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Bibliothek</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'schwestern', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Schwestern</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option your looking for is "Reuse Matched Parameters" as described here

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html

You can optionally NOT reuse these parameters, however, before making that choice, I would take a long hard look at your routing strategy and make sure your resources and sub resources are organized in a logical way you want to support going forward.